# ListBox or ItemControl items don't take up all available space

Tags: wpf, silverlight

Sorry if this has been answered before; I've looked at similar posts here but the suggested fix isn't working for me.

I'm working on a Silverlight 3 project and I have the following:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}"
         >
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
     </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

The ListBox is bound to a source, which uses different DataTemplates using a DataTemplateSelector that I implemented in Silverlight.

The ListBox seems to ignore the style property HorizontalContentAlignment, i.e. I can't get the items to stretch to the whole width of the ListBox.

My DataTemplates look like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" Name="{Binding ID}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Basically, I want the items to fill all the available space of the ListBox control, and share them so that the left half of the space is occupied by the TextBlock, and the right half is occupied by the TextBox.

Any ideas on how to do this?

EDIT: @wdavo: Here's the TemplateSelector code:

```
// http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/92439/Silverlight-DataTemplateSelector
public abstract class DataTemplateSelector : ContentControl
{
  public virtual DataTemplate SelectTemplate(
    object item, DependencyObject container)
  {
    return null;
  }

  protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
  {

    base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent);
    ContentTemplate = SelectTemplate(newContent, this);
  }
}
public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
  public DataTemplate MyTemplate1 { get; set; }
  public DataTemplate MyTemplate2 { get; set; }
  public DataTemplate MyTemplate3 { get; set; }

  public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
  {
    var element  = item;

    if (element.GetType() == typeof(MyType1))
      return MyTemplate1;
    else if (element.GetType() == typeof(MyType2))
      return MyTemplate2;
    else if (element.GetType() == typeof(MyType3))
      return MyTemplate3; 

    return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
  }
}
```

and the xaml:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateSelector">
    <local:MyTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}">
        <local:MyTemplateSelector.MyTemplate1>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" Name="{Binding ID}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:MyTemplateSelector.MyTemplate1>
        ... and so on
    </local:MyTemplateSelector>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you need to set the HorizontalAlignment and HorizontalContentAlignment properties to stretch within your TemplateSelector.

E.g.

```
 <ContentPresenter
            Content="{Binding Item}">
            <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:TemplateSelector
                        Content="{Binding}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```

As mentioned you should also you a Grid instead of a StackPanel

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where do I put this ContentPresenter object? Is it a child of my DataTemplate selector? or the parent?

Comment: I think you just need to add the HorizontalAlignment and HorizontalContentAlignment properties to your  <local:MyTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}">

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. (adding HorizontalAlignment and HorizontalContentAlignment to the TemplateSelector and using a Grid instead of a StackPanel. Using a StackPanel doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

You should just use a `Grid`. The `StackPanel` is only using the minimum space needed by each element.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" Name="{Binding ID}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This worked in combination with wdavo's suggestion to set the alignment in the template selector.

Comment: Just a question.. If I have it like this, the text box expands when I input more text than the box can handle. It eats into my textblock's half.. Is there a way to explicitly tell the grid to just set each item to use half the space?

Comment: Doesn't the textblock come first? So the textbox is expanding backward? Either way, the answer I posted shouldn't let this happen. You might want to ask this as a different question.

Comment: Actually, it could be doing this if the horizontal alignment of the textbox is set to `Stretch`. If it is, try setting it to something else instead.

Comment: Yes, the textblock expands backwards, meaning the textbox becomes smaller as the textblock gets bigger, if there is not sufficient space. I will try setting the horizontal alignment of the textbox to a different value.. :)

Comment: Hmm, if I don't use stretch, it doesn't fill the space that the grid allocated for it. However, if I type stuff in, it expands until it fills the grid's allocated space and then stops expanding..

Comment: I got it! I set the TextBox HorizontalAlignment to Left, and the TextBlock to Stretch.. Now the TextBox doesn't give way and the Textblock doesn't expand.. :)